# How to Encode an Image into an HTML file

Tags: html, image, encoding

So this may be a weird question,  but bear with me. I am designing a block of code for a website. I am creating a

```
<div></div>
```

element with all the content inside it. 
Style tags are included within it, as are script tags. For ease of design, they wish for only an HTML file with the script and CSS inside of it. I also have a background image that I am using. It is used elsewhere on the webpage, and SHOULD show up when the code is inserted into the website> However, since I have no way of verifying this, I would like to include the image into the HTML file. I am NOT talking about the image tag (as below)

```
<img src='image.jpg/>
```

I am talking about somehow including or encoding the image into the physical HTML file, So that there isn't a separate HTML file and JPEG file, but just one HTML file. Is this even possible? If so, how?

EDIT: Thanks for the help with Base64, but that can be rather long, and add a whole bunch of length to the HTML file. Are there any OTHER possible solutions?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can base64 encode the image data, so you would end up with something like this

```html
<img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhDwAPAKECAAAAzMzM/////
wAAACwAAAAADwAPAAACIISPeQHsrZ5ModrLlN48CXF8m2iQ3YmmKqVlRtW4ML
wWACH+H09wdGltaXplZCBieSBVbGVhZCBTbWFydFNhdmVyIQAAOw=="
alt="Base64 encoded image" width="150" height="150"/>
```

Here are some resources:

[Base64 image converter](http://base64image.org/)

http://www.bigfastblog.com/embed-base64-encoded-images-inline-in-html

[Embedding Base64 Images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207190/embedding-base64-images)

Comment: this works everywhere?

Comment: I'm not sure about EVERYWHERE.  If you read the third link, the Stack Overflow post, you will see the list of browsers that support this.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme#Web_browser_support

Comment: @mittmemo5 thanks. Appreciate the help.

Comment: unwrapped version of the above example
 <img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhDwAPAKECAAAAzMzM/////wAAACwAAAAADwAPAAACIISPeQHsrZ5ModrLlN48CXF8m2iQ3YmmKqVlRtW4MLwWACH+H09wdGltaXplZCBieSBVbGVhZCBTbWFydFNhdmVyIQAAOw==" alt="Base64 encoded image" width="150" height="150"/>

Comment: I wish more email clients supported this.